# How to make a class property type in C ++ as is how it is done in C#

Tags: c++, class

as the code below made for example purposes in C #, I would have had to do in C ++, if so how do you do?

```
public class MyClassTest{
    public int testint1{get;set;}
    public MyClassTest2 classTest2{get;set;}
}
public class MyClassTest2{
    public int testint2{get;set;}
    public MyClassTest classTest{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: There's no standard equivalent in C++, just like Java. Although it might be possible as a library in C++17 *shrug*.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
class MyClassTest {
private:  // optional: C++ classes are private by default
    int testint1;
public:
    int getTestInt1() const { return testint1; }
    void setTestInt1(int t) { testint1 = t; }
};
```

Or you could make your member name distinct and skip the get/set keywords:

```
class MyClassTest {
private:
    int testint1_;
public:
    int testint1() const { return testint1_; }
    void testint1(int t) { testint1_ = t; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to this in the current C++ standard, you just have to create getter/setter methods for any fields you want:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {}
    // note const specifier indicates method guarantees
    // no changes to class instance and noexcept specifier
    // tells compiler that this method is no-throw guaranteed
    int get_x() const noexcept { return x; }
    void set_x(int _x) { x = _x; }
private: 
    int x;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio (mine is 2013), it could be done in this way:

```
__declspec(property(get = Get, put = Set)) bool Switch;

bool Get() { return m_bSwitch; }
void Set(bool val) { m_bSwitch = val; }

bool m_bSwitch;
```

in a Class.